# Create an optional foreign key using the Fluent-API for Entity Framework 7

Tags: foreign-keys, option-type, fluid, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create an optional foreign key using Entity Framework 7 and the Fluent-API. In EF v6.x we had the option to add this using `.WithOptional` or `.HasOptional`, but I cant find any equivalent functionality in EF 7.. any ideas?

Br,
Inx

Comment: Look in the docs: http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#foreign-key

Comment: Docs were moved to https://docs.efproject.net

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Found the answer.. you can pass in "false" as a parameter to .IsRequired()..
For instance:

```
            EntityShortcut<ContentEntity>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Children)
            .WithOne(e => e.Parent)
            .IsRequired();
```

That would be an requried relation

```
            EntityShortcut<ContentEntity>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Children)
            .WithOne(e => e.Parent)
            .IsRequired(false)
```

While that would NOT be a required relation.

FYI:

```
private static EntityTypeBuilder<T> EntityShortcut<T>() where T : class
{
    return _modelBuilder.Entity<T>();
}
```